# EF Core on .net5 - AddDbContext not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

This has been driving me up the wall as there should be no reason why AddDbContext in startup.cs isn't working. Anyone have any thoughts?

Project specs: .net 5, EF Core 5, MVC

PsContext.cs

```
public PsContext()
{
}

public PsContext(DbContextOptions<PsContext> options)
    : base(options)
{
}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("name=PSDB");
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<PsContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PSDB"));
});
```

Appsettings.json

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "PSDB": "Server=xxxxxx;Database=xxxxxxx;User ID=xxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
},
```

I scaffolded my DB Entity without issue by using the following command in Package Manager Console

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection name=PSDB Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Entities -f
```

However when running the application, I encounter this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A named connection string was used,
> but the name 'PSDB' was not found in the application's configuration.
> Note that named connection strings are only supported when using
> 'IConfiguration' and a service provider, such as in a typical ASP.NET
> Core application. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=850912
> for more information.'

As requested, here is the program.cs as well

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    config.Sources.Clear();
                    var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                          .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                          .AddEnvironmentVariables();
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

Comment: Well, based on the error message, it appears you have a problem with your configuration files.  We would need to see your program.cs where you configure your configuration.  Do you use the default builder?  Specifically the CreateHostBuilder method in there.

Comment: Where you put `ConnectionStrings` in appsettings,in`{}`?

Comment: Looks like you have code which is using the `public PsContext()` parameterless constructor which triggers the code `optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("name=PSDB");` inside the `OnConfiguring` override. You need to find that code. The simplest is to remove that constructor (and `OnConfiguring` override).

Comment: @RobertMcKee 

I've added my program.cs up in the post above

Comment: @YiyiYou Correct in between '{}'. I am able to get other appsettings values

Comment: @IvanStoev would you not need the parameterless constructor to initialise a database connection?

Comment: `AddDbContext` uses the other constructor (with `DbContextOptions<PsContext> options`) to create context instances. And these are configured, in your case with `options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PSDB"));`. Using the parameterless constructor directly (e.g. `new PsContext()`) is problematic,  and you must have such code somewhere that you need to find and eliminate.

Comment: Try removing your entire `.ConfigureAppConfiguration` everything you are doing there is the default for .NET 6.0, and reasonably sure it is the same for .NET 5, but wouldn't swear to it.  Also, if this is running under linux, BSD/mac, or on a file system other than NTFS, please make sure your "Appsettings.cs" is actually cased "appsettings.cs"